# React - How to redirect to another component on Search?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router

So I'm working on an app for school and I've been stuck on an issue for like two days. I'm building a search that gets data from TMDB, and all that works fine. When I type in the input all the data come flowing in! However, when I submit and try to redirect to the /results page which is linked to a component that displays the SearchResults when directed to, nothing happens and it stays on the homepage... I tried Redirect but either I'm using it incorrectly, or I shouldn't be using it in this case. Here's the code for my Search component, if you could help me out, I'd greatly appreciate it!:

```
import React, { Component, Redirect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    results: []
  };

  getInfo = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=6d9a91a4158b0a021d546ccd83d3f52e&language=en-US&query=${
          this.state.query
        }&page=1`
      )
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          results: data
        });
      });
  };

  handleInputChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        query: this.search.value
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
          if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
            this.getInfo();
          }
        } else if (!this.state.query) {
        }
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            className='search'
            placeholder='⌕'
            type='text'
            ref={input => (this.search = input)}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
        {this.state.results.length > 0 && (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/results',
              state: { results: this.state.results }
            }}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Search;
```

Comment: AFAIK `React.Redirect` does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `withRouter` to get history prop injected and then do: `history.push(“/results”)`

The code will look something like this:

```
import React, { Component, Redirect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from "react-router";

class Search extends Component {
  state = {
    query: '',
    results: []
  };

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  const { history } = this.props;
  if (prevState.results !== this.state.results) {
    history.push('/results');
  }
  }

  getInfo = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/tv?api_key=6d9a91a4158b0a021d546ccd83d3f52e&language=en-US&query=${
          this.state.query
        }&page=1`
      )
      .then(({ data }) => {
        this.setState({
          results: data
        });
      });
  };

  handleInputChange = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState(
      {
        query: this.search.value
      },
      () => {
        if (this.state.query && this.state.query.length > 1) {
          if (this.state.query.length % 2 === 0) {
            this.getInfo();
          }
        } else if (!this.state.query) {
        }
      }
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input
            className='search'
            placeholder='⌕'
            type='text'
            ref={input => (this.search = input)}
            onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(Search);
```

This way you are *programmatically* navigating, using *push* method from react router's history.

Here you can read more about *withRouter* HOC: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Comment: For some reason, that method isn't working for me either. Maybe it's how I have my app set up... I'd have to show someone the Github repo and see if they can find any errors. This is weird haha

Comment: @JavontayMcelroy what do you mean by isn’t working? Show me a console error or tell me what’s happening. We are missing something 

Comment: Well i guess 'technically' it's working, it's not logging any errors, however, /results isn't being pushed to the end of the url. It does go from localhost:3000 to localhost:3000/? whenever I hit enter...

Comment: @JavontayMcelroy have you got any buttons in that view? Try adding to them the prop *type=‘button’*

Comment: I don't have any buttons, no... The only thing being rendered is the search input and that has a type='text'. Want to analyze my repo? I feel like it could be an issue with my routes in my App.js file. But I'm not sure...

Comment: @JavontayMcelroy I’ll take a look in an hour or two. Send me the link

Comment: Thank you! Here's the link: https://github.com/javontaymcelroy/spectre/tree/master/spectre-tv

Comment: I edited the answer to make it work. You still have some challenges to face. but using this fix your Search component will redirect to '/results' when you type in

Comment: This way, you're comparing array references to know when to push to '/results', it only happens once because *history* knows when you're trying to push to the same route and it prevents the page from reloading

Comment: DUDE YOU'RE AMAZING!! Thank you!! God, I would've never figured that solution out! Thank you!

Comment: Guess the next challenge would be passing the props down into SearchResults lol.

Comment: Yes! Here is all you need: https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you using React Router for routing?. Do you need to change your URL? There isn't much of a need for something like this. Sending someone to `/results` is just old school unless you are going to do something like `/results?q=pulp&amp;piction` so someone can refresh or link directly to the results.

For something like this just display your result component

```
{this.state.results.length && (
  <SearchResults results={this.state.results} />
)}
```

If you are using a router and need to use the path for the school project school your teacher for dumb business requirements and give us more information about what you are using.

Comment: I'll try your solution. I don't need a path, just was told to use it lol.

Comment: So, The information that's being past into SearchResults is just displaying under the search field and not switching the Home component to the SearchResults component. :(

Answer (score 0):

"Redirect" component is inside the "react-router-dom" package.
use this approach:

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Search extends Component {
//...

render() {

    const { results } = this.state
    const { props } = this.props

    return (results.length > 0 ? <Redirect
        to={{
            pathname: "/results",
            state: {
                results: results,
                from: props.location
            }
        }}
    /> : <form>
            <input
                className='search'
                placeholder='⌕'
                type='text'
                ref={input => (this.search = input)}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
        </form>
    )
}
```

}